# Spring config additional location as environment variable in docker-compose

Tags: java, spring-boot, docker-compose

I am trying to tell Spring to add properties from a file, which is outside the jar.

https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html#boot-features-external-config-application-property-files

I have docker compose file where I define environment variables for Spring Boot application.

```
 sample-service:
    build:
      context: "./sample-service/app"
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    container_name: sample-service
    restart: always

    mem_limit: 400000000
    env_file: .env
    environment:
      - "SPRING_PROFILE=dev"
      - "APPLICATION_NAME=sample-service"
      - "SPRING_CONFIG_ADDITIONAL-LOCATION=file:/app/sample-service-config.yml"
      - "JAVA_OPTIONS=-agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=*:5006"

    ports:
      - 5006:5006
```

When I am in the debugger, I execute custom code.

```
System.getenv("SPRING_PROFILE")
```

It returns `dev`. When I run

```
System.getenv("APPLICATION_NAME")
```

It returns `sample-service`. When I run

```
System.getenv("SPRING_CONFIG_ADDITIONAL-LOCATION")
```

It returns `null`.

---

**Update**

Some people suggest that docker does not support hyphens
https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/2370

Comment: I know that bash can't have hyphen in variable name, maybe this is related

Comment: then why don't you try with underscored ?

Comment: @Deadpool, it still does not work.

Comment: with underscore this is still null or the properties isn't loads? please notice that the value of `SPRING_CONFIG_ADDITIONAL-LOCATION` should point to directory

Comment: @matanper, both! Environment variable is null and properties are not loaded. I found a solution, I answered my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, it is crazy...

I changed my Dockerfile which starts this Java application, so now I can pass additional configuration location as a command line argument. I also added a bash script to start my Java app.

**Dockerfile**

```
ENTRYPOINT ./startJavaApp.sh
```

**startJavaApp.sh**

```
java -XX:+UseContainerSupport $JAVA_OPTIONS -jar ../sample-service.jar --spring.config.additional-location=file:/app/sample-service-config.yml
```

Looks like passing it as a command line argument did work.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the following format:

```
env_file: .env
  environment:
    - SPRING_PROFILE=dev
    - APPLICATION_NAME=sample-service
    - SPRING_CONFIG_ADDITIONAL-LOCATION="file:/app/sample-service-config.yml"
    - JAVA_OPTIONS="-agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=*:5006"
```

**REFERENCE**
 - [Environment variable for docker compose](https://docs.docker.com/compose/environment-variables/)

Comment: It still returns `null`, after I put such variable into .env file.